# I'm using Yii addColumnCondition and want to change the default behaviour from '=' to using LIKE and %

Tags: php, search, yii, sql-like, criteria

I'm using the `addColumnCondition` function as I like how it forms the queries for multiple queries. But I can't find anything in the documentation to change it's comparison operation from the simple `= needle` to a `LIKE %needle%`. There is a function that does a `LIKE` in `addSearchCondition()` but then it means to get the same query formation result, I'll have to do some for loops and merge conditions which I'd like to avoid if there is a better solution.

Here's the code

```
foreach($query_set as $query){
    foreach($attributes as $attribute=>$v){
        $attributes[$attribute] = $query;
    }
    $criteria->addColumnCondition($attributes, 'OR', 'AND');
}
```

And I'm getting the condition formed like

```
(business_name=:ycp0 OR payment_method=:ycp1) AND (business_name=:ycp2 OR payment_method=:ycp3)
```

So is there a way to configure the function to use `LIKE %:ycp0%` instead of the simple `=:ycp0`.

Comment: Hi there .. Sorry I didn't accept this earlier .. I had seen your answer but just got around to using it today .. and yes it indeed worked .. Thank you very much !! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems, this feature is not provided by Yii's addColumnCondition method.

therefore i would recommend a way of overriding the method of CDbCriteria class and customize it your own way.

you need to create a new class called **"AppCriteria"**, then place it inside **protected/models**

The code for the new class should look like,

i.e

```
class AppCriteria extends CDbCriteria {

   public function addColumnCondition($columns, $columnOperator = 'AND', $operator = 'AND', $like = true) {
      $params = array();
      foreach ($columns as $name=>$value) {
         if ($value === null)
            $params[] = $name.' IS NULL';
         else {
            if ($like)
               $params[] = $name.' LIKE %'.self::PARAM_PREFIX.self::$paramCount.'%';
            else
               $params[] = $name.'='.self::PARAM_PREFIX.self::$paramCount;
            $this->params[self::PARAM_PREFIX.self::$paramCount++] = $value;
         }
      }
      return $this->addCondition(implode(" $columnOperator ", $params), $operator);
   }
}
```

**Note:** The 4th param of addColumnCondition, **$like = true**. you can set it to **$like = false** and allow the function to work with equal conditions. (A = B)

i.e

```
(business_name=:ycp0 OR payment_method=:ycp1) AND (business_name=:ycp2 OR payment_method=:ycp3)
```

if **$like = true**, it will allow you to have like condition. (A like %B%)

i.e

```
(business_name LIKE %:ycp0% OR payment_method LIKE %:ycp1%) AND (business_name LIKE %:ycp2% OR payment_method LIKE %:ycp3%)
```

Now Here's the working code,

```
$criteria = new AppCriteria();
foreach($query_set as $query){
    foreach($attributes as $attribute=>$v){
        $attributes[$attribute] = $query;
    }
    $criteria->addColumnCondition($attributes, 'OR', 'AND');
}
```